# Cross-fragment communication

Tags: android, sqlite, list, tabs, android-fragments

I am working on an app that has an "artist list", a list of a good chunk of music bands, performers and/or composers. They are sorted by genre and relative popularity.
From the main activity you go to a "band list" activity that has two tabs in it. One of them is a "genres" tab that has a list of the general music genres and when you click on each genre you get sent to the respective activity that also has two tabs in it. The first one is the "All" tabs and the other one's the "Popular" tab. Each of the tabs holds a fragment that contains a filtered sqlite database (by "filtered" I mean I have one big database that gets filtered to show what I want in different fragments rather than using a new database for each fragment/genre). So now I have 7 genres and 14 classes; 2 ("all" and "popular") for each genre.
What I would like to do now is reduce the number of classes to only two (all/popular) or, if possible, even one, by recycling the same fragment for all lists via filtering the database again. In order to do this I need to send a string from the "genres" fragment, containing the position of the pressed list item (genre) to the activity which contains the "All" and "Popular" tabs (fragments), which will then send that string further, to the fragments, which will use it to filter the sqlite database.

I need to add that I have, of course, read the Android Developers guide on fragment communication, but I do not know how to use their approach in my code, since I have created the fragments a little differently, including not defining them in the xml, so because of that I don't know how to use their `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);` method and some more things like that.

Here is the TabListener via which I am creating all fragments:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Aleksa

Comment: You could use the callback methods detailed in the Developer Guide, and set a variable in your host activity from there. Then you could have the other fragment read that variable from the main activity..

Comment: That is exactly why I wrote the last paragraph... How do I use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);` if I don't have the <fragment code in the xml where I would specify the id?

Comment: Fragments don't need to be defined in xml to use the callback methods, and you don't need the id of the fragment to pass information to and from it. I don't see why you need to use findFragmentById(), use the callbacks to pass information to the host activity, and programmatically retrieve that information when a new fragment is instantiated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trying I eventually gave up on setArguments() and getArguments() and used this in the parent activity:
`public int getPosition(){ return position; }`
...and this in the child fragment:
`position=((ParentActivity) getActivity()).getPosition();`
I don't know if it is the most efficient method around but it works great and makes sending some simple data to a fragment a trivial thing for newcomers like me as it should be. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you created the fragments programmatically and added them with a tag, u can use the support FragmentManager method: findFragmentByTag(String tag)

Comment: thanks for the reply!
I am currently sending data from the genres fragment to the bandlist activity by adding an extra to my intent no prob, but when i try to send data from that activity to its child fragment by using setArguments() and getArguments() I get a nullpointerexception in this line (in the fragment) `genre=getArguments().getInt("position");`. Any tips?